# AWS lambda function URLs with JSON input in Java giving JSON parse exception

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, function, url, aws-lambda

I have created a AWS Lambda function as follows,

```java
public class PiiDecryptionLambda implements RequestHandler<Map<String, String>, String> {

    public PiiDecryptionLambda() {
    }

    @Override
    public String handleRequest(Map<String, String> requestData, Context context) {
        LambdaLogger logger = context.getLogger();
        logger.log("inside the lamda and the data is :"+requestData);
        return requestData.get("name");
    }
}
```

Then i have configured the Funtion URL for the lambda function. when try to access this from post using Function URLs given the AWS lambda, getting following error

> An error occurred during JSON parsing: java.lang.RuntimeException
> java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred during JSON parsing
> Caused by: java.io.UncheckedIOException:
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not
> deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_OBJECT token  at
> [Source: lambdainternal.util.NativeMemoryAsInputStream@42e26948; line:
> 1, column: 1] Caused by:
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not
> deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_OBJECT token  at
> [Source: lambdainternal.util.NativeMemoryAsInputStream@42e26948; line:
> 1, column: 1]     at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:148)
> at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.mappingException(DeserializationContext.java:857)
> at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StringDeserializer.deserialize(StringDeserializer.java:62)
> at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StringDeserializer.deserialize(StringDeserializer.java:11)
> at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader._bindAndClose(ObjectReader.java:1511)
> at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader.readValue(ObjectReader.java:1102)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `Map<String, Object>` or create a custom pojo for the expected object.

AWS also has example for this:

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-lambda-developer-guide/blob/main/sample-apps/java-basic/src/main/java/example/HandlerWeatherData.java